# MAX(col1) to get previous value

Tags: oracle

Is there a 'short hand' way of using something like MAX(?) to get the previous (2nd to max) value?
I was hoping something simple like `MAX((colval)-1)` type thing! :-)

Rather than doing the long winded

```
SELECT MAX(col) WHERE NOT IN (select MAX(col))...;
```

Comment: Could you please tell us the version of your oracle server?

Comment: if the ordered values of colval is 3, 3, 2,  ... what is the previous (2nd to max) value? 3 or 2?

Answer (score 1):

Considering this the data below (with ties):

```
colval
-------
  1
  2
  3
  4
  5
  6
  7
  7
  7
```

This is the shortest way that comes to mind :

```
select distinct colval
  from (select colval, dense_rank() over(order by colval desc) as rn
          from [TableName])
 where rn = 2
```

Which returns number 6.